# Javascript getDate() before this month

Tags: javascript, html

I have some pure javascript calendar.
my problem is that I want to add the days before the choosen month.

```
|so|mo|di|mi|do|fr|sa|
______________________
|29|30|31|1 |2 |3 | 4| <-- here 29,30,31
______________________
|5 |6 |.....
```

I hope it's clear what I mean. Here my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calendar(id, year, month) { 
  var elem = document.getElementById(id)

  var mon = month - 1  // (1)
  var d = new Date(year, mon)

  var table = ['<table><tr>']

  for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')         // here days before this mounth
  }

  // main body (3)
  while(d.getMonth() == mon) {
    table.push('<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')

    if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {   // (4)
      table.push('</tr><tr>')
    }

    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)  
  }

  n = 1
  for (var i=d.getDay(); i<8; i++) {

    table.push('<td>' + (n++) + '</td>')

  }

  table.push('</tr></table>')

  elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}
new Calendar("cal", 2015, 9)
</script>
```

I try around with setDate() but I don't mastered it jet.

Comment: You can call `.setDate()` with negative numbers to get the last days of the previous month, and with numbers bigger than 30 (or 31 or whatever) to get the first days of the next month.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use expression (such as `d.getDay()`) in a loop condition. It will be evaluated each time the loop is iterated. So it's better to store the expression's value in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments setDate (and the Date constructor) can have negative values. But instead of a `pre` and `post` loop, you could set the startdate to the beginning of the week and always add entire weeks:

```
function Calendar(id, year, month) { 
  var elem = document.getElementById(id)

  var mon = month - 1;  // (1)
  var d = new Date(year, mon, 1 );
  var start = 1-d.getDay();  

  var table = ['<table>'];
  while(d.getMonth() <= mon) {
      table.push('<tr>');
      for(var i =0 ; i< 7; i++){
          d = new Date(year,mon,start++);
          table.push('<td>'+d.getDate() + '</td>')
      }      
      table.push('</tr>');    
  }
  table.push('</table>')

  elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}
new Calendar("cal", 2015, 9);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2k3qac/)

edit: an alternate version just in case the 'other' months should have a lighter colour: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2k3qac/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot... is it also possible to start at monday?

Comment: you're welcome :) . Sure, I reused the current setup, but to start on monday just use `var start = 2-d.getDay();`  ( http://jsfiddle.net/rj2k3qac/2/ )

Answer (score 0):

`Date` object has method `.setDate()` for adding days to get updated date.

```
var someDate = new Date(2015, 06, 05); // (year, month, date)
console.log('old date : ' + someDate);
var numberOfDays = 6; // No of day add or remove. use negative sign for remove days
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDays); //date object with new date (new day, new month and new year)
console.log('new date : ' + someDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining start and end dates for your month view and iterate from start to end.

```
var startDate = new Date(d);
var endDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate() - 1);

while (startDate.getDay() != 0) {
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);
}

while (endDate.getDay() != 6) {
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it in this way:

```
  tmp = new Date(year, mon, 0).getDate() // return day of the last month
  for (var i=0; i<(d.getDay() + 6) % 7; i++) { // count days
    table.splice(1,0,'<td>'+(tmp-i)+'</td>') // adding days at first pos of table
  }
```

Thanks